# Antlr v3 error with parser/lexer rules

Tags: parsing, antlr3, lexer

I am having problems with my Antlr grammar. I'm trying to write a parser rule for 'typedident' which can accept the following inputs:

'int a' or 'char a'

The variable name 'a' is from my lexer rule 'IDENT' which is defined as follows:

```
IDENT : (('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') | '_') (('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')|('0'..'9')| '_')*;
```

My 'typedident' parser rule is as follows:

```
typedident : (INT|CHAR) IDENT;
```

`INT` and `CHAR` having been defined as tokens.

The problem I'm having is that when I test 'typedident' the variable name has to be more than one character. For example:

`'int a'` isn't accepted while `'int ab'` is accepted.

The outputed error I get is:

> "MismatchedTokenException: mismatched input 'a' expecting '$'"

Any idea why I'm getting this error? I'm fairly new to Antlr so apologies if the error is trivial.

**EDIT**

I literally just got it working, and I don't know why. I also had two other lexer rules defined as follows:

```
ALPH : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'); 
DIGIT : ('0'..'9');
```

I realised these weren't being used at all so I deleted them and everything now works fine! My guess why this works is because `ALPH` and `DIGIT` were overriding my other Lexer rules:

```
NUMBER : ('0'..'9')+; 
CHARACTER : '\'' (~('\n' | '\r' |'\'')) '\'';
```

Does anyone know if this is the case? I'm curious as to why this problem has now been solved.

Comment: I literally just got it working, and I don't know why.

I also had two other lexer rules defined as follows:

    ALPH  : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z');
    DIGIT : ('0'..'9');

I realised these weren't being used at all so I deleted them and everything now works fine!

My guess why this works is because ALPH and DIGIT were overriding my other Lexer rules:

    NUMBER  : ('0'..'9')+;
    CHARACTER : '\'' (~('\n' | '\r' |'\'')) '\'';

Does anyone know if this is the case? I'm curious as to why this problem has now been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'int a' isn't accepted while 'int ab' is accepted.
>   ...
>   My guess why this works is because ALPH and DIGIT were overriding ...

Yes, it appears `ALPH` was defined before the `IDENT` rule, in which case single letters were tokenized as `ALPH` tokens. If `IDENT` was defined *before* `ALPH`, it should all go okay (in your case).

To summarize how ANTLR's lexer rules work:

- lexer rules match as much characters as possible (greedy);
- if 2 (or more) lexer rules match the same input, the rule defined first will *"win"*.

You must realize that the lexer does not produce tokens based on what the parser (at that time) needs. The lexer operates independently from the parser.