# Antlr identifier with AND does not match

Tags: antlr, antlr3

Using Antlr 3.5 rule:

```
ID
 : ':'? ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_')*
 ;
```

does not match: **standard**

Could anyone explain why?

Below is the complete grammar. You can use rule **colname** to test against "standard".

```
grammar Sql;

options {
  language = Java;
  output = AST;
}

@rulecatch {catch (RecognitionException e) { throw e;}}

@header {
  package com.something.antlr.sql;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
}

@lexer::header {
  package com.something.antlr.sql;
}

@members {
 private List<Table> tables = new ArrayList<Table>();
 private List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<Column>();

 private StringBuilder joinClauses = new StringBuilder();

 private String withClauseAsString;
 private String tablesAsString;
 private String columnsAsString;
 private String aggregate;
 private String whereClauseAsString;
 private String orderByAsString;
 private String groupByAsString;
 private String limitAsString;

 public List<Table> getTables() {
  return tables;
 }

 public String getColumnsAsString() {
    return columnsAsString;
 }

 public List<Column> getColumns() {
    return columns;
 }

 public String getTablesAsString() {
    return tablesAsString;
 }

 public String getJoinClauseAsString() {
    return joinClauses.toString();
 }

 public String getWhereClauseAsString() {
    return whereClauseAsString;
 }

 public String getOrderByAsString() {
    return orderByAsString;
 }

 public String getAggregate() {
    return aggregate;
 }

 public String getGroupByAsString() {
    return groupByAsString;
 }

 public String getWithClauseAsString() {
    return withClauseAsString;
 }

 public String getLimitAsString() {
    return limitAsString;
 }


}


sql_statement
  : sql EOF;
   catch [RecognitionException e]{ throw e;}

sql
:
  (WITH with_clause)?
    {withClauseAsString = $with_clause.text;}
  SELECT DISTINCT? (TOP LPAREN? t=number_or_param RPAREN?)? columns?
      {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if ($DISTINCT.text != null) {
          sb.append(" distinct ");
        }

        if ($TOP.text != null) {
          sb.append(" top ");
        }

        if ($t.text != null) {
          sb.append(" ");
          if ($LPAREN.text != null) {
            sb.append("(");
          }
          sb.append($t.text);
          if ($RPAREN.text != null) {
            sb.append(")");
          }
          sb.append(" ");
        }

        sb.append($columns.text);
        columnsAsString = sb.toString();
      }
      (
      FROM tables*
           {tablesAsString = $tables.text;}

    (join_type? JOIN join_clause)*
     {
       String joinClauseAsString = "";

       if ($join_type.text != null) {
         joinClauseAsString = $join_type.text + " ";
       }

       if ($join_clause.text != null) {
        joinClauseAsString += $join_clause.text;
       }

       if (joinClauseAsString.length() > 0) {
          joinClauses.append("\n ");
          joinClauses.append(joinClauseAsString);
       }

     }

    (WHERE where_clause)?
          {whereClauseAsString = $where_clause.text;}

    (ORDER_BY order_by_clause)?
          {orderByAsString = $order_by_clause.text;}

    (GROUP_BY group_by_clause)?
          {groupByAsString = $group_by_clause.text;}
    (LIMIT t2=number_or_param)?
          {
            if ($t2.text != null) {
              limitAsString = " limit " + $t2.text;
            }
          }

    (UNION ALL? alt_sql)?
    )?
  ;


with_ident
:
  ID
;

with_clause
:
  with_ident (LPAREN columns RPAREN)? AS alt_sql
;


alt_sql
:
  LPAREN?
  (
  SELECT DISTINCT? (TOP number_or_param)? columns?
    FROM tables*
    (join_type? JOIN join_clause)*
    (WHERE where_clause)?
    (ORDER_BY order_by_clause)?
    (GROUP_BY group_by_clause)?
    (LIMIT NUMBER)?
    (UNION ALL? alt_sql)?
  )
  RPAREN?
;

exists_select
:
  SELECT NUMBER FROM tables (WHERE where_clause)?
;

in_select
:
  SELECT colname FROM tables (WHERE where_clause)?
;

colname_or_operand
:
 colname | LPAREN ID RPAREN | RANGE | CONSTANT |  TICK '*' TICK | alt_sql
;

case_test
:
  (ID '.')? function (CALC function)* operator (ID | NUMBER)
;

colname
:
  //CASE WHEN case_test ( (AND | OR) case_test)* THEN (NUMBER | ID) ELSE (NUMBER | ID) END alias
  CASE (WHEN where_logical THEN (ID | NUMBER | LITERAL))+ ELSE (ID | NUMBER | LITERAL) END alias
  |
  col = ID alias?
    {
    Column c = new Column($col.text, "");
    columns.add(c);
    }
  |
  tbl=ID '.' col=ID ('::' ID)? alias?
    {
    Column c = new Column($tbl.text + "." + $col.text, $alias.text);
    columns.add(c);
    }
  |
  (ID '.')? '*'
  |
  (ID '.')? func_name = function alias?
    {
    Column c = new Column($func_name.text, $alias.text);
    columns.add(c);
    }
  |
  col = (ID '::' ID)
    {
    Column c = new Column($col.text, "");
    columns.add(c);
    }
  |
  ('?' | NUMBER | LITERAL) (('::' | AS) ID)?
    {
    Column c = new Column("?", "");
    columns.add(c);
  }
;

columns
:
  (colname (CONCAT colname)* | alt_sql alias?) (',' (colname (CONCAT colname)* | alt_sql alias?))*
;

tablename
:
  ID alias?
    {
    Table tbl = new Table($ID.text, $alias.text);
    tables.add(tbl);
    }
  |
  (ID '.')? function alias?
  |
  t = TABLE LPAREN func = ID LPAREN arguments RPAREN RPAREN alias?
    {
    Table tbl = new Table($t.text + "(" + $func.text + "(" + $arguments.text + ")" + ")", $alias.text);
    tables.add(tbl);
    }
;

arguments
:
  argument (',' argument)*
;

argument
:
  colname
;

tables
  : tablename (',' tablename)*;


join_sql
:
  LPAREN
  SELECT DISTINCT? columns
  FROM tables*
  (WHERE where_clause) RPAREN alias
  ON where_expression
;


join_type
:
  ('left' 'outer'? | 'LEFT' 'OUTER'? | 'Left' 'Outer'?) | ('right' 'outer'? | 'RIGHT' 'OUTER'?  | 'Right' 'Outer'?)
;

join_clause
  :  (alt_sql alias | tablename alias? | colname) ON where_clause
  ;

alias
:
  AS? ID
;


exists_clause
:
  EXISTS LPAREN exists_select RPAREN
;

in_clause
:
  LPAREN (LPAREN in_select RPAREN alias? | in_values) (',' (LPAREN in_select RPAREN alias? | in_values))* RPAREN
;

in_values
:
  (NUMBER | LITERAL) (',' (NUMBER | LITERAL))*
;

where_expression
:
  LPAREN* ((colname operator (colname_or_operand | in_clause)) | exists_clause?) RPAREN*
;

where_logical
:
  LPAREN* where_expression ((AND | OR) where_expression)* RPAREN*
;

where_clause
:
  where_logical ((AND | OR) where_logical)*
;

number_or_param
:
  NUMBER | '?'
;

order_by
:
  (ID | NUMBER) (ASC | DESC)?
;

order_by_clause
  : order_by (',' order_by)*;

group_by_clause
:
  ID ('.' ID)? (',' ID ('.' ID)?)*
;

BETWEEN
:
 'between' | 'BETWEEN' | 'Between'
;


operator
  : '=' | '<' | '>' | '<=' | '>=' | '<>' | 'is' | 'Is' | 'IS' | BETWEEN |  IN |  'like' | '&lt;=' | '&gt;=' | '&lt;&gt;';

CALC
:
  '+' | '-' | '/'
;

function
:
  ID LPAREN DISTINCT? arguments? RPAREN ('::' ID)?
;

CONSTANT
:
  TICK ID TICK
;

LITERAL
:
  TICK .* TICK
;

TABLE : ('t' | 'T') ('a' | 'A') ('b' | 'B') ('l' | 'L') ('e' | 'E');
WITH : 'with' | 'WITH' | 'With';
SELECT : 'select' | 'SELECT' | 'Select';
DISTINCT : ('d' | 'D') ('i' | 'I') ('s' | 'S') ('t' | 'T') ('i' | 'I') ('n' | 'N') ('c' | 'C') ('t' | 'T');
TOP : 'top' | 'TOP' | 'Top';
CASE : ('case' | 'Case' | 'CASE');
WHEN: ('when' | 'When' | 'WHEN');
THEN : 'then' | 'Then' | 'THEN';
ELSE : 'else' | 'Else' | 'ELSE';
END : 'end' | 'END' | 'End';
FROM : 'from' | 'FROM' | 'From';
EXISTS : 'exists' | 'EXISTS' | 'Exists';
WHERE : 'where' | 'WHERE'| 'Where';
JOIN : ('left' | 'LEFT' | 'Left' | 'right' | 'RIGHT' | 'Right')? 'join' | 'Join' | 'JOIN';
ON : 'on' | 'ON' | 'On';
AND : ('a' | 'A') ('n' | 'N') ('d' | 'D');
AS : ('a' | 'A') ('s' | 'S');
OR : ('o' | 'O') ('r' | 'R');
IN : 'in' | 'IN' | 'In';
ORDER_BY : ('o' | 'O') ('r' | 'R') ('d' | 'D') ('e' | 'E') ('r' | 'R') ' ' ('b' | 'B') ('y' | 'Y');
ASC : ('a' | 'A') ('s' | 'S') ('c' | 'C');
DESC : ('d' | 'D') ('e' | 'E') ('s' | 'S') ('c' | 'C');
GROUP_BY : 'group by';
UNION : ('u' | 'U') ('n' | 'N') ('i' | 'I') ('o' | 'O') ('n' | 'N');
ALL :  ('a' | 'A') ('l' | 'L') ('l' | 'L');
LIMIT : 'limit' | 'LIMIT' | 'Limit';
CONCAT : '||';
TICK: '\u0027';

LPAREN
: '('
;

RPAREN
: ')'
;

RANGE
:
  (ID | '?') AND (ID | '?')
;

NUMBER
  : ('0'..'9')+;

ID
 : ':'?('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_')('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_')*;

WHITESPACE
 : (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r' | '\f')+  {$channel = HIDDEN;};
```

Comment: it *does* match it, but some other rule in your grammar might match it too.

Comment: The problem here is that the rule:

like_id
:
  ID
;

does not match "standard" when I run it in ANTLRWorks 1.5 Interpreter using this rule in isolation. How can it match another rule in such a case?

Comment: Sorry, I can't comment on something I can't see. Could you add your grammar? If you're reluctant to post the whole thing, be sure to post enough of it so that I, or someone else, can actually reproduce it.

Comment: Bart, I appreciate your trying to help! However, I just realized that the ANTLRWorks Interpreter cannot run in isolation, i.e. it cannot check single rule without taking the whole grammar into account.

Comment: The interpreter cannot, but the debugger can parse any rule you specify (be it a parser- or lexer rule). However, if you try `like_id : ID ;` in the debugger and it fails, it means there is another lexer rule that matches `"standard"` before `ID` can match it. This is because the lexer operates independently from the parser. It does not matter that the parser is trying to match an `ID`, the lexer will go its own way in creating tokens. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251048/antlr-v3-error-with-parser-lexer-rules

Comment: I cannot run Debugger because of "Connection Error - Cannot launch the debuggerTab. Time-out waiting to connect to the remote parser".

Comment: The port the debugger is trying to connect to is occupied by something. Choosing a different port in the settings will likely resolve this. But checkout my answer as well.

Comment: You should also place all lexer rules after all parser rules. Specifically, you should place the `BETWEEN` rule after the `operator` rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lexer has an issue with `"standard"` because you also defined a `RANGE` rule:

```
RANGE
 : (ID | '?') AND (ID | '?')
 ;
```

that could tokenize `"standard"` as:

- `ID` (`"st"`)
- `AND` (`"and"`)
- `ID` (`"ard"`)

Note that a such a rule shouldn't be a lexer rule because it doesn't mandate there be any spaces in between such tokens. This is a parser rule:

```
range
 : (ID | '?') AND (ID | '?')
 ;
```

After making that change, I'm sure `"standard"` will be tokenized as a `ID` token.

Comment: This works great, thank you! I wish Antlr provides a message that would describe it in such details.