# antlr3 - read closure value to a variable

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

I would like to parse and read a closure value in a simple text line like this:

**1 !something**

```
line
    :   (NUMBER EXCLAMATION myText=~('\r\n')*)
{ myFunction($myText.text); }

NUMBER
    :   '0'..'9'+;

EXCLAMATION
    :   '!';
```

What I get in *myText* variable is just the final 'g' of 'something' because as can see in generated code *myText* is rewrited in a while loop for each occurence of *~('\r\n')*.

My answer is: is there any elegant way to read the 'something' value to the variable 'myText'?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside parser rules, the `~` does not negate characters, but tokens. So `~('\r\n')` would match any token other than the literal `'\r\n'` token (in your example, that would be a `NUMBER` or `EXCLAMATION`).

The lexer cannot be "driven" by the parser: after the parser matched a `NUMBER` and a `EXCLAMATION`, you can't tell the lexer to produce some other tokens than it has previously done. The lexer will always produce tokens based on [some simple rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251048/antlr-v3-error-with-parser-lexer-rules), regardless of what the parser "needs".

In other words: you can't handle this in the parser.